# Youtube scraping - cant import "build" from google-api-python-client

Tags: python, import, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Im writing a scraping software using youtube API and google OAuth credentials, i have a problem with this line:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

Im using PyCharm, python version 3.9, version of this package google-api-python-client is 2.114.0

As it seems, there is some conflicts between my packages, but i dont know what exactly may cause this problem. I tried to uninstall some of connected official packages from google, but it still doesnt work for me. My google-auth 2.23.4 google-api-core 2.15.0 google-auth-oauthlib 1.1.0 google-auth-httplib2 0.2.0

Comment: Please be more specific about what "a problem" is. Share the traceback if you're getting one.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my path", line 29, in <module>
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)
NameError: name 'googleapiclient' is not defined

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Reading [ask] would probably be useful for you as well. It looks like you should be writing `youtube = build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)` based on your `import` statement.

Comment: 1) Method names such as `build()` are very common in Google Cloud SDKs. I prefer to use `googleapiclient.discovery.build` to prevent conflicts. 2) Your post does not show the conflict details. 3) Use Python Virtual Environments to prevent/reduce package conflicts.